# Fetching and Adding Checkbox dynamically on selection of Dropdown boxes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, dynamic, http-get

[image: Form]

I have a form as above. I am trying to work as when user selects Table Name & Permission, it goes back to server side, fetches the columns of the selected table & display all column names as check boxes. When use selects Save btn, HttpPost will execute and when user selects Cancel, to return back to home page.

I have created a ViewModel for this :

```
 // Actual EF Model
    public partial class TablePermission
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int PermissionLevelId { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get; set; }
    public string RestrictViewFields { get; set; }
    public string RestrictEditFields { get; set; }

    public virtual PermissionLevel PermissionLevel { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
// View Model for the View
public class TablePermissionsVM
{

    public TablePermissionsVM()
    {
        TablePermission = new TablePermission();
        RestrictViewFields = new List<FieldList>();

        // Created for trial to see Checkboxes 
        RestrictViewFields.Add(new FieldList() { FieldName = "UserId", Selected = false });
        RestrictViewFields.Add(new FieldList() { FieldName = "fName", Selected = false });
        RestrictViewFields.Add(new FieldList() { FieldName = "lName", Selected = false });

        RestrictEditFields = new List<FieldList>();
    }

    public TablePermission TablePermission { get; set; }

    public List<FieldList> RestrictViewFields { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<FieldList> RestrictEditFields { get; set; }
}

// Model to save field names & it's selected status
public class FieldList
{
    public string FieldName { get; set;  }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
}
```

Controller **UPDATED** : ADDED THE NEW ACTION (FillFields() ) METHOD that has to called onChange event

```
       [Authorize]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TablePermissions(TablePermissionsVM tablePermissionVm)
    {
        return View(tablePermissionVm);
    }

    // Action Method to Fill Column names for the List<>.
    public ActionResult FillFields(string tableName, string tblPermLevel)
    {
        // WANT TO RETURN HERE ANOTHER LIST (2 LIST OBJECTS) IN JSON
        // restrictView & restrictEdit 
        var restrictView = DbUtilities.GetColumnNames(tableName);
        var restrictEdit = DbUtilities.GetColumnNames(tableName);
        return Json(restrictView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

View - **UPDATED CODE** : aDDED Bound fields for TableName & TableLevelPermission, Script that I use on the event of change of Table Selected.
**UPDATED** - aDDED FORM ID, SCRIPT METHOD

```
       @model DataStudio.Models.TablePermissionsVM

using (Html.BeginForm("TablePermissions", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "tblPermForm" }) ))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TablePermission.TableName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TablePermission.TableName, 
                    DbUtilities.GetTableNames(), "Select Table", 
                    new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="FillFields()" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TablePermission.TableName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.TablePermission.PermissionLevelId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TablePermission.PermissionLevelId, DbUtilities.GetPermissionLevelList(), "Select Permission Level", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TablePermission.PermissionLevelId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

       <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RestrictViewFields, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="editor-field">
                 **// NEED TO ADD CHECK BOXES HER RECEIVED THRU SCRIPT** 
            </div>
        </div>
  }

<script>
    function FillFields() {
        var tblName = $('#TablePermission_TableName').val();
        var tblPermLevel = $('#TablePermission_PermissionLevelId').val();

        //($('tblPermForm').valid()) { ERROR - OBJECT DOESN'T HAVE valid()'
        if (tblName != null && tblPermLevel != null) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Admin/FillFields',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: "JSON",
                data: { TableName: tblName, TablePermLevel: tblPermLevel },
                success: function (restrictView) {
                    $("#RestrictViewFields").html("");  // Clear before appending new ones
                    $.each(restrictView, function (i, field) {
                        $("#RestrictViewFields").append(
                            $('<option></option>').val(field.FieldName).html(field.FieldName))  
                  // WANT TO ADD AS 3 CHECKBOX IN A ROW
                    });

                }
            });
        }
    }
  </script>
```

Their are couple of things that I am not able to figure out & get confused with it. Mainly, on making sure that both the drop down boxes has value, I need to perform again a "Get" and fetch column names for the table selected & display the columns as check boxes. 
The way I have implemented Checkboxes, I will get proper selected Values in HttpPost, Right ! Are am I anywhere wrong ?

How to make the Get Request when both the drop down's are selected ??

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

**Update** I started to try with only TableName selection (I want for both dropdown), but the event doesn't occur and go to FillFields() in script. Where am I going wrong ? I tried this logic from [here](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1145/mvc-dropdownlistfor-fill-on-selection-change-of-another-dropdown) . Can't get why it doesn't get fired only ??? 
Btw, this is a full form i mean, their is no partial form in it. I want to fill the check box controls in those 2 RestrictXFields on selection of TableName & Permssion check box & on Save btn, send all to Request & save to db.

**UPDATE** : THANKS a lot, Stephen & Chethan. With your support, I identified the cause for event not getting triggered. Event is triggered, I am able to retrieve the column names from db, the HTML part on success is not being updated. Stephen, I also added form Id & tried form.valid() as you instructed, but I get error script doesn't identify valid(). Both the fields in Model are marked as Required in MetaData class. Currently, testing both var != null works. But, I liked you valid() option.

Comment: Why make another round trip by posting just the value of the `<select>`'s? You can use ajax to call a server method that returns your checkboxes based on the selection and update the DOM

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I tried that way and have updated my code. But the event never gets fired. Can you please look at code and help me know where I am going wrong in the code.

Comment: verfiy if your script is actually rendered on the page? and check the TableName dropdown markup in browser.

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code, but you have not even shown your `FillFields()` method and your `data: { TableName: TableName },` makes no sense (you do not have a variable named `TableName ` - I assume you mean `data: { TableName: tblName },`? What errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: And you do not have an element with `id="TableName"` (if you want the value of the `<select>` it would be `$('#TablePermission_TableName').val()`

Comment: @Chethan, yes the script is rendered on the page. The only difference is see is in inspect line, I find the id of this control as id = TablePermission_TableName & in my script I have used just as #TableName. I am trying using in scriot as var tblName = $('#TablePermission_TableName').val();

Comment: @StephenMuecke, I have already added FillFields() Action in the Controller. Ys, I corrected with this part - data: { TableName: tblName } . Reg id="TableName", in the tutorial it was said to use the property name as id, so I had used that way. But now am trying with what you have mentioned.

Comment: Inspect the html your code is generating to see the `id` attribute :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, how do I make sure that FillFields() script method has the non-empty values of both id="TablePermission_PermissionLevelId" and id="TablePermission_TableName"  and then only make call to ajax Controller Action ?

Comment: Though my Action FillFields() returns 0 count, empty & appending checkbox is not working. Html - <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="RestrictViewFields">RestrictViewFields</label>
                <div class="editor-field">
                        // NEED TO FILL CHECK BOXES HERE !!!
                </div>
            </div>        i believe here again the problem is of id. Wish to have 3-4 checkboxes in each row. What code to add to implement the same, Columns will vary on table selected.

Comment: You just need to first check that both are not `null`  e.g. `if (tblName && yourOtherVariable){ make ajax call };` but it would be far better to have your properties decorated with the `[Required]` attributes so that you can first check if the form is valid - e.g. `if ($('form').valid() { make ajax call }` so that you valdation errors are displayed

Comment: You have not shown the `FillFields()` controller method so I cannot comment on that, but in any case there are a lot of other issues with your code. No time now, but I'll see if I can find some links for you that explain how you should be approaching this later.

Comment: // Action Method to Fill Column names for the List<>.
    public ActionResult FillFields(string tableName)
    {
        var restrictView = DbUtilities.GetColumnNames(tableName);
        return Json(restrictView, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

Comment: You need to add the relevant information in the question (not in comments)

Comment: Added dear. You mightt have to scrroll down the Controller part to see the FillFields() Action. Have updated the code that's working by now as per guidance got thru here. I would highly appreciate, if you can Please write your answer with other guidance to complete the total part of the question.I have done & have been doing research to figure out solution for this. Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per my understanding, You should fetch the checkboxes using an ajax call.

Create an action method in your controller which accepts selected values of TableName and TableLevelPermisson dropdown. Use these values to fetch

```
List<FieldList> RestrictViewFields  
IEnumerable<FieldList> RestrictEditFields.
```

and use as data/model to your partial view.

Call this action method using ajax, on change of the dropdown list value. 
Get the HTML returned from partial view and use it in your DOM.

How to make the Get Request when both the drop down's are selected ??

> > If you are using jQuery: Just google for "dropdown change events in jquery" and ajax call examples.

Comment: the drop down values of TableName & TableLevelPermission are already associated with model.TablePermission.TableName & model.TablePermission.TableLevelPermission respectively. I have updated my question & added some code that I have tried with ajax call, but it doesn't work. Can you please look at it and help me know where am I going wrong ! Thanks

Comment: Can you show me what HTML this line is producing:  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.TablePermission.TableName, 
                    DbUtilities.GetTableNames(), "Select Table", 
                    new { @class = "form-control", @onchange="FillFields()" }) ??

(Inspect element in browser): should show something like this:

<select class="form-control" id="TablePermission.TableName" name="TablePermission.TableName" onchange="FillFields()">
<option value="1">Name1</option>
<option value="1">Name1</option>...
</select>

Comment: <select name="TablePermission.TableName" class="form-control" id="TablePermission_TableName" onchange="FillFields()" data-val-required="Select Table Name to set Permission for User " data-val="true"><option value="">Select Table</option>
<option value="[dbo].[Permission]">Permission</option>
<option value="[dbo].[PermissionLevel]">PermissionLevel</option>
<option value="[dbo].[Role]">Role</option>
<option value="[dbo].[User]">User</option>
<option value="[dbo].[UserRoles]">UserRoles</option>
<option value="[dbo].[TablePermission]">TablePermission</option>
</select>